# Creating service instance when needed

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

I have a Controller class that maps request urls. I have an instance of class annotated with `@Service`. For example;

```
@Controller
class MainController{
  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;
  ...
}
```

As I know, this instance is created automatically by Spring container, because I added `@Autowired` but I use this instance when condition is met in the method. If the condition is not met, I do not need this instance. Thus, this declaration is overhead. I mean, I may not use it even though it is created.

I would like to create the object when it is needed. How can I do this in the code? I probably will not use `@Autowired` because I need a dynamic object creation. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Ths instance is not created because you have Autowired. it is created because it is a bean

Comment: Yes, so i will not include @Autowired.

Comment: If you wish to do that, then you should not declare userService as a bean and Create an instance by yourself when needed

Comment: I declare UserService class with "@Service". Then, I will remove this annotation from UserService class?

Comment: yes, `@Service` is what is making it a Spring bean. Irrespective of you use @Autowired or not it will be created by Spring.  But I don't see the point in doing so. Be default all spring beans are singletons. i.e. there will be only one instance of UserService class. So what is the issue.

Comment: Ok, then what is the point of defining instances with "@Bean" or "@Service"?. I see all examples with those annotations.

Comment: @Eric What do you mean? As been told before, `@Service`  can be used on top of a class to tell that Spring should create a bean for it. `@Bean` on the other hand can be used in a configuration class to tell Spring that it should create a bean for it.

Comment: @g00glen00b , I know that "Bean" objects are created in class anotated with "@Configuration". Can I create service instance as bean with the type prototype, not in the controller class??

Answer (score 1):

You can use Setter injection. The @Autowired annotation can be used on setter methods. In the below example, when the annotation is used on the setter method, the setter will be called with the instance of FooFormatter when FooService is created:

```
public class FooService {

private FooFormatter fooFormatter;

@Autowired
public void setFooFormatter(FooFormatter fooFormatter) {
        this.fooFormatter = fooFormatter;
}
}
```

In this way you can inject you service when you call the setter method explicitly :) Hope this will help you :)

**LATER EDIT**

I've just found a way that might resolve your problem, it's named @Lazy.

You can use @Lazy annotation like this:

1. On your service class, put @Lazy annotation before the public Class XXX definition;

   2. When declaring/autowiring a Service type in your controller context, put @Lazy annotation with @Autowired annotation on top of the declared attribute like

   @Lazy
   @Autowired
   private FooFormatter fooFormatter;

for more info, check the link: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation

Comment: so I will use this??

fooService.setFormatter(new FooFormatter);

Comment: Yeah, you can create a setter for your service and put @Autowired annotation on this. In this way you will ensure that the service will be injected when the controller will be created.

Comment: But I want to create this service instance when a specific condition is met, not when the controller is created. If it is created with the controller. It will be redundant. I mean, it will be waste of resource in memory.

Comment: How about creating the instance in getter method in Configuration? and then use this method in the controller??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @Lazy annotation with a combination of Bean Life Cycle annotations. But one thing you need to consider is the performance of your controller if you will re-create your service each time you need it, then you degradates the performance.